# How to delete these specified columns?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to delete specific columns to all sheets in a workbook. When I run my codes, it will only remove the columns specified in the first line. The rest are not included. How do I do it with many columns to specify? How do I go about this?

```
Sub Dosomething()
  Dim xSh As Worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each xSh In Worksheets
      xSh.Select
      Call DeleteColumns
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub DeleteColumns()
  Dim ColumnsToDelete As String, V As Variant
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "AAFA Certified|AATCC 116 Grade|AATCC 16.1-2014 Grade|AATCC 16.3-2014 Grade|AATCC 8 Grade|AC Rated|AC Rating|ACT Flammability Guidelines Compliant|ADA Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Additional Intended Use For Child|AHAM CADR Dust rating|AHAM CADR Pollen rating|AHAM CADR Smoke rating|AHAM Certified|AHMA Compliant|AHRI Certified|American Cornhole Association (ACA) Certified|ANSI A117.1 Compliant|ANSI A137.1 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ANSI IT9.2 Compliant|ANSI Z1.5A/CGA 9.1M Certified|ANSI Z124.1.2 Compliant|ANSI Z124.3 Compliant|ANSI Z124.6-97 Compliant|ANSI Z358 Compliant|ANSI/BHMA A156 Certified|ANSI/BIFMA e3 Furniture Sustainability Standard|ANSI/BIFMA X5.1 Office Seating|ANSI/BIFMA X5.11 Large Occupant Office Seating"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ANSI/BIFMA X5.3 Vertical Files|ANSI/BIFMA X5.4 Lounge & Public Seating|ANSI/BIFMA X5.5 Desk Products|ANSI/BIFMA X5.6 Panel Systems|ANSI/BIFMA X5.9 Storage|ANSI/BIFMA X6.1 Educational Seating|ANSI/BIFMA X7.1 Standard for Formaldehyde & TVOC Emissions|ANSI/ESD S20.20 Certified|ANSI/NISO Z39.48 Compliant|ANSI/SOHO S6.5 Small Office/Home Office"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "APMA Certified| ASHRAE 62.2 Standard Compliant| ASME A112.18.1 Compliant| ASME A112.18.2 Compliant| ASME A112.19.1 Compliant| ASME A112.19.2 Compliant| ASME A112.19.3 Compliant| ASP:02:01 Certification| ASSE 1001 Certified| ASSE 1006 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ASSE 1016 Certified| ASTM E1590-07| ASTM F1004-19 Certified| ASTM F1148-17| ASTM F1148-18 Certified| ASTM F1169 - 13 Certified| ASTM F1821 - 16 Certified| ASTM F1912-17 Certified| ASTM F1917 - 12 Certified| ASTM F2057 - 14 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ASTM F2057 - 17 Certified| ASTM F2057 - 19 Certified| ASTM F2085 - 12 Certified| ASTM F2088-15| ASTM F2194 Certified| ASTM F2225-15| ASTM F2388 - 18 Certified| ASTM F2613 - 17 Certified| ASTM F2933-18 Certified| ASTM F3084 - 16 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ASTM F3096 - 14 Certified| ASTM F3317-18 Certified| ASTM F381-16| ASTM F406 - 10a Certified| ASTM F406 - 15 Certified| ASTM F406 - 17 Certified| ASTM F963 - 17 Certified| ASTM F963-11| ATA Rated| AZO Free"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "BHFTI Upholstered Furniture Flammability Compliant| BIFMA G1 Ergonomics Guideline for Furniture| BIFMA HCF 8.1 - Healthcare Furniture Design| Blauer Engel| BPA Free| BS 5287: 1988 Certified| BS 5852 Certified| BS 5867-2:2008 Certified| BS 7176: 2007 Certified| BS 7177:2008+A1:2011 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "BS EN 13120: 2009 + A1: 2014 (Requirements for Window Blinds or Drapery Cords) - EU ONLY| BS EN 71 Compliant - EU ONLY| BS EN 716-1 Compliant - EU ONLY| BS EN12790 Certified| Bulb Included| Bulb Type| CAL TB 116 Compliant| CAL TB 117-2013 Compliant| CALGreen Compliant| California AB 1953 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "California Pesticide (DPR) Registration Number| California Proposition 65 Warning Required| Canada Product Restriction| CARB Phase II Compliant (formaldehyde emissions)| CE Certified| CEE Rating| Certifications| CertiPUR-US Certified| cETL Certified| cETL Listed"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CFC Free| Chemicals of Concern Compliant| Children’s Product Certificate (CPC)| CISPR 22 Compliant| Commercial ONLY Certifications| Commercial OR Residential Certifications| Commercial Warranty| Composite Wood Product (CWP)| Consumer Safety Specification for Bunk Beds ASTM F1427 - 13| Contains Flame Retardant Materials"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Country of Origin| Country of Origin - Additional Details| CPAI-84 Compliant| CPG Compliant| CPSC - 15 U.S. Code § 1278a - Children’s Products Containing Lead| CPSC - 16 CFR 1213 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1217 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1218 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1219 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1220 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CPSC - 16 CFR 1234 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1237 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1238 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1239 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1303 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1500.49 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1513 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1630 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1631 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1632 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CPSC - 16 CFR 1633 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR Part 1130-Requirements For Consumer Registration Of Durable Infant Or Toddler Products| CPSC - 16 CFR Part 1307-Prohibition Of Children's Toys And Child Care Articles Containing Specified Phthalates| CPSIA Compliant| CPSIA or CPSC Compliant| Cradle to Cradle Certified| CRI Certified| CRI Green Label Certified| CRI Green Label Plus Certified| CSA B125 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CSA B125.1 Certified| CSA B125.2 Certified| CSA B13 Certified| CSA B45 Certified| CSA B45.1 Certified| CSA B45.2 Certified| CSA Certified| CSA Listed for Canada| CSA Listed for USA| cUL Listed"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "cUPC Certified| Dark Sky Compliant| DECT 6.0 Compliant| DIN EN 12935 Certified| Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - CAN| Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - USA| EEP Compliant| EIA Compliant| EISA 2007 Compliant| EISA Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Emergency Feed| EN 1130-1:1996 (Safety Requirements for Cribs and Cradles) - EU ONLY| EN 12221-1 (Standards for Changing Tables) - EU ONLY| EN 13219 (Standards for Trampolines) - EU ONLY| EN 14878: 2007 (Requirements for Children's Sleepwear) - EU ONLY| EN 14988-1 (Safety Standards for High Chairs) - EU ONLY| EN 15312 (Safety Standards for Multi-Sport Equipment) - EU ONLY| EN 1725 (Safety Standards for Adult Beds) - EU ONLY| EN 1930 (Standards for Child Gates and Safety Barriers) - EU ONLY| EN 50291-1 (Standards for Smoke Detectors and CO Detectors) - EU ONLY"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "EN 54-12 (Standards for Smoke Detectors and CO Detectors) - EU ONLY| EN 71 Compliant| EN 71-14:2018 Compliant| EN 747-1 (Standards for Childrens Bunk Beds) - EU ONLY| EN 748 (Safety Standards for Football Goals) - EU ONLY| Energy Label Type| Energy Policy Act 1992 Compliant| Energy Star Compliant| EPA Compliant| EPA Pesticide Registration Number"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "EPAct 2005 Compliant| EPP Compliant| ETL Listed| EuroLatex ECO-Standard| FCC Compliant| FCC Part 15 Certified| FCC Part 15 Compliant| FCC Part 68 Compliant| FDA Approved| FIRA Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Fire Rated| Fire Resistant| FISP Certified| FloorScore Certification| FM Approved| FourB Compliant| FSC Certified| General Certificate of Conformity (GCC)| Glass Doors and Enclosures Regulations SOR/2016-174| Glazed Ceramics and Glassware Regulations SOR/2016-175"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "GOLS 3.0 (Global Organic Latex Standard) Certified| GOLS License Expiry Date| GOLS License Number| Goodweave Certified| GOTS 5.0 (Global Organic Textile Standard) Certified| GOTS License Expiry Date| GOTS License Number| Grade of GOLS Certification| Grade of GOTS Certification| Green Compliance"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "GREENGUARD Certified| GREENGUARD Gold Certified| GS (Geprüfte Sicherheit) verzeichnet| GSA Approved| Health Canada - SOR/2016-176 Compliant| Health Canada - SOR/2016-179 Compliant| Health Canada - SOR/2016-183 Compliant| Health Canada Compliant| HFES 100 Certified Ergonomic| HVI 2100 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "HVI Certified| IAPMO Certified| IATA Compliant| Indoor Air Quality Certified| IP Rating| IPEMA Certified| ISO 14000 Certified| ISO 14001 Certified| ISO 9000 Certified| ISO 9001 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ITSF Compliant| ITTF Approved| ITTO Compliant| Janka Hardness Rating (PSI)| JPMA Certified| Kettles Regulations SOR/2016-181| Knife Included| Lacey Act Compliant| Latex Free| Lead Free"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "LEED Project Appropriate| LM-79 Certified| LM-80 Certified| Low Lead Compliant| Mattress Flammability Testing - Public Occupancy Use| Maximum Wattage (per bulb)| MERV Rating| MET Listed| Minnesota 325F.177 Compliant| MOHS - Surface Hardness"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "NAECA Certified| NAHB Compliant| NEMA Certified| NFPA 253 or ASTM E648 Certified| NFPA Compliant| NFSI Certified| NHPA Approved| NOMITE Certified| Non-Toxic| NRPA Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "NSF Certified| NSF/ANSI 184 Certified| NSF/ANSI 3 Certified| NSF/ANSI 336 Compliant| NSF/ANSI 61 Certified| OEKO-TEX Standard 100 Certified| OSHA Compliant| PAT Tested| PEFC Certified| PEI Rated"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "PEI Rating| PFOA Free| Phthalate Free| Product Warranty| PTFE Free| PTFE or PFOA| PTFE or PFOA Free| Reason for Restriction| Responsible Down Standard Certified| RoHS Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "SATRA Approved| SCC Compliant| SCS Certified| SDWA Compliant| SFI Certified| SOR/2016-152 - Canadian Regulation - Cribs, Cradles and Bassinets| SOR/2016-193 - Surface Coating Materials Regulations| SOR/2018-83 -Consumer Products Containing Lead Regulations| Stiftung Warentest Note| TAA Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "TB 117-2013 Compliant| TB 133 Compliant| TCLP Compliant| Textile Flammability Regulations SOR/2016-194| Textile Labelling and Advertising Regulations (C.R.C., c. 1551)| Tipover Restraint Device Included| Title 20 - California Code of Regulations| Title 24 Compliant| Total Recycled Content (Percentage)| Total Wattage"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Toys Regulations SOR/2016-195| TSA Compliant| TSCA Title VI Compliant (formaldehyde emissions)| TÜV Certified| TÜV Rheinland zertifiziert| UL 10B Compliant| UL 10C Compliant| UL 1678 Listed| UL 1951 Listed| UL 2108 Listed"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "UL 4041 - Safety Standard for Outdoor Furniture| UL Listed| ULC ORD-C627.1-2008 - Unvented Ethyl Alcohol Fuel Burning Decorative Appliances| ULC/ORD-C627.1-2008| Uniform Packaging and Labeling Regulations (UPLR) Compliant| UPC Certified| USATT Approved| USDA Compliant| USDA Organic/ NOP Certified| USDA/NOP Certificate Number"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "USDA/NOP License Expiry Date| USPS Approved| Vermont Act 193 Compliant| VESA Compliant| Washington State VIAQ Code Compliant| Wattage| WEEE Recycling Required| WQA Gold Seal Certified| WW-P-541 Certified"
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each V In Split(ColumnsToDelete, "|")
    Rows(1).Find(Trim(V), , , xlWhole, , , False).EntireColumn.Delete
  Next
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: list the column by their reference rather than name, ie "A:C" etc

Comment: Ctrl+H, find `_`, replace by an empty string. Then Ctrl+H again, find `ColumnsToDelete =`, and replace by `ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & `, and that should be good to go.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I did what you said, it deleted the first line, but the second and moving forward, they are not deleted.

Comment: @alowflyingpig But the workbooks that we edit don't have the same column sequence all the time.

Comment: Try it again.. make sure to select "in procedure", not just "selection"

Comment: @MathieuGuindon What's that? I am sorry. I am new to this and still practicing. Click Insert then Procedure. Then that's where I will place the Dosomething or the DeleteColumns sub?

Comment: In the find/replace dialog, there's a series of optionbuttons that determine where to search: in the current selection, the current procedure, the current module, the entire project

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have updated my post. Check the new codes above. I did what you asked and edited in the current procedure. Yes, it only deleted the first line. The second line and onwards, they still remain.

Comment: I don't understand. Your code looks fine here. Still "too many line continuations"?

Comment: Possibly starting from the 2nd row of string concatenation the code line should include a prefixed colon to each further string sequence, i.e. `ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "," & "..."` to identify each sequence starter correctly (and separated by the "," delimiter) instead of combining it with the last preceding string element :-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The too many lines continuation error no longer occurs. However, the result is still the same. Only the first line is working. The second line and onwards are not deleting the columns specified. Thanks for your help with the too many line continuations error though! Appreciate it!

Comment: @T.M. I am confused with your instructions. I am sorry. Can you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: The `Split` function needs a "," delimiter to separate the string tokens correctly. If the last column name in the 1st line and the first column name in the new line have no "," in between, these two names won't be identified. So I assume the second code line should start with an additional colon, i.e. `ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "," & "Additional Intended Use For Child,AHAM CADR Dust rating,....."`, similarly the 3rd line and so forth :-)

Comment: The post title and body is about too many line continuations, but the code isn't, and the actual question is buried in a bunch of comments. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon done. Thank you.

Comment: @T.M. Thank you so much! It's working now! One last thing. I have column names like "Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - CAN". VBA is reading it like "Dry" and "Damp" "or Wet Location Listed - CAN". How can I make it as one?

Comment: @Jezun 1) Change the "," in `Dry, Damp, or Wet ...` to an unused character within the `ColumnsToDelete` assignment rows, e.g. to "$" and 2) *replace* the  `V` variable back in the loop, e.g. via `Rows(1).Find(Trim(Replace(V, "$", ","), , , xlWhole, , , False).EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: this stopped working. I just noticed that after all, it only deletes the word Certifications, and the rest after that is ignored

Comment: @T.M. Can you help? :(

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing your complete (manual) changes (c.f. `Dry, Damp, or Wet ...` ~> `Dry$ Damp$ or Wet ...`) Suppose you overwrote other delimiters :-)